# dell xps 15 9550 hibernate/suspend problem ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dell, hibernate, xps

I have a dell xps 15 9550, from a couple of weeks when I hibernate or suspend pc,and after when I try to switch on it doesn't wake up.I have to shutdown it using power button.

Kernel version 4.4.0-36
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using `systemctl suspend` ?

Comment: yes, but when I try to turn it on the screen remains black

Comment: Same problem here. Probably BIOS or display driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At time or writing, the workaround was to [downgrade your BIOS to 1.2.0](http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER03659467M/1/XPS_9550_1.2.0.exe)

An alternative is to log in (although you don't see your login screen), and then pump up your brightness to max.

For your configuration, keep an eye on [this wiki.](http://wiki.yobi.be/wiki/Laptop_Dell_XPS_15)

**UPDATE (Alternative Solution for 16.04):**

This also solved the problem for me on a newer version of the BIOS:

Create a script:

`sudo nano /lib/systemd/system-sleep/97fixbacklight`

Contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
# From patchwork.freedesktop.org/.../
# and en.community.dell.com/.../19985320
# Suspend Resume fails to restore PWM_GRANUALITY
# Based on script by Tony.Jewell@Cregganna.Com


INTEL_REG=/usr/bin/intel_reg
ADDR="0x000c2000"
SAVE_FILE=/var/lib/systemd/save_intel_reg_pwm_granuality


[ -x "$INTEL_REG" ] || exit 0


case "$1" in
        pre)
        echo "$0: Saving Intel Register PWM_GRANUALITY"
        "$INTEL_REG" read "$ADDR" \
            | (read addr value && echo "$value") \
            >"$SAVE_FILE"
    sync
    ;;
    post)
        value=`cat "$SAVE_FILE" 2>/dev/null`
        if [ -n "$value" ]
        then
            echo "$0: Restoring Intel Register PWM_GRANUALITY $value"
            "$INTEL_REG" write "$ADDR" "$value"
            rm "$SAVE_FILE"
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

Give it the right permissions:

`sudo chmod +755 /lib/systemd/system-sleep/97fixbacklight`

Restart

Comment: Worked for me on 17.04